# C++ underflow and overflow

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how underflow and overflow works in C++. My understanding is that if a variable's range is exceeded, it will start from the other end of the range. Thus if the minimum of `short` is -32768 and if we subtract 1 from it, the new value should be `SHRT_MAX` (32767).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int testpositive = INT_MIN;
  short testnegative = SHRT_MIN; 
  cout << SHRT_MIN << "\n";
  cout << testnegative - 1 << "\n";
  cout << INT_MIN << "\n";
  cout << testpositive - 1 << "\n"; 
  cout << testpositive - 2;
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Operands are promoted to `int` first so there's no overflow.  Consider casting the result back to short to see what you are hoping for.

Comment: Amazing.It works and now I understand .

Comment: Consider using `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <iostream.h>`.

Answer (score 13):

The exact behavior on overflow/underflow is only specified for `unsigned` types.

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Source: [Draft N3690 §3.9.1 sentence 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

> This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
> unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the
> resulting unsigned integer type.

Source: [Draft N3690 Note 47 for §3.9.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

For normal signed integer types instead the C++ standard simply says than anything can happen.

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined

Source: [Draft N3690 §5 sentence 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

If we're talking about x86 processor (or most other modern processors) indeed the behavior is exactly what you describe and for the CPU there is no difference between a signed value or an unsigned value (there are signed and unsigned *operations*, but the value themselves are just bits).

Note that compilers can assume (and most modern optimizing compilers actually DO assume) that no signed integer overflow can occur in a correct program and for example in code like:

```
int do_something();
int do_something_else();

void foo() {
    int x = do_something();
    int y = x + 1;
    if (x < y) {
        do_something();
    } else {
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

a compiler is free to skip the test and the `else` branch in the generated code completely because in a valid program a signed int `x` is always less than `x+1` (as signed overflow cannot be considered valid behavior).
If you replace `int` with `unsigned int` however the compiler must generate code for the test and for the else branch because for unsigned types it's possible that `x > x+1`.

For example clang compiles the code for `foo` to

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        push    rax
        call    do_something()
        pop     rax
        jmp     do_something()       # TAILCALL
```

where you can see that the ode just calls `do_something` twice (except for the strange handling of `rax`) and no mention of `do_something_else` is actually present. More or less the same code is generated by `gcc`.

Comment: The thing is modern compilers take advantage of signed overflows being undefined behavior to perform optimizations. So even if at the CPU level the behavior is defined, it is not a guarantee your program is not invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @ouah: Yes... added a note about assumptions compilers are free to do when analyzing the code

Comment: Could we please have a specification link to the definition of unsigned underflow? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasWeller: n3690 says "Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer" and as a note "This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type".

Comment: @6502: thanks, answer is edited to cite and link the document.

Answer (score 3):

Signed overflows are undefined behavior in C++.

For example:

`INT_MIN - 1`

`-INT_MIN`

are expressions that invoke undefined behavior.

`SHRT_MIN - 1` and `-SHRT_MIN` are not undefined behavior in an environment with 16-bit `short` and 32-bit `int` because with integer promotions the operand is promoted to `int` first. In an environment with 16-bit `short` and `int`, these expressions are also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Typically yes. But since this is C++, and C++ is regulated by the C++ standard, you must know that overflows are **undefined behavior**.

Although what you stated probably applies on most platforms, it's in no way guaranteed, so don't rely on it.

Comment: *signed* overflows are undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The new value need not be `SHRT_MAX` it is undefined.

Comment: The behavior is undefined.  The program could very well crash.