# Ones-complement or sign-magnitude integer representation platform?

Tags: operating-system, integer, cpu-architecture

What are the most common present day platforms, computer architectures, processors, operating systems and/or compilers that use either ones-complement or sign-magnitude integer representations?

Comment: As noted in the [Wikipedia article on signed number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), Unisys' ClearPath Dorado (a.k.a. IX) series uses one's complement. The [Wikipedia page for the architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) also indicates that it used a non-power-of-two word size (36 bits). (Javascript's use of DP FP even for "integer" values might *almost* be considered use of sign-magnitude integer representation, but that seems to be stretching things.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any non-twos-complement implementations of C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c)

Answer (score 0):

NO common present day platforms uses anything other than 2s-complement to represent integers.

Comment: Technically, "most common" does not have to be common.

Comment: Every standard involving binary data (e.g., JPEG, GZIP) presumes the use of 2s-complement. The first computer I used was one of those 36-bit unisys's. They no longer exist, exempt in museums.

Comment: While there seems to be a push toward running legacy code on a software layer over x86 (this would still count as a "platform" even if not hardware), it seems that [hardware implementations are still being offered](http://www.unisys.com/unisys/theme/index.jsp?id=1120000970018010225). With such systems, the hardware tends to stay in use (with vendor support) significantly after the last new hardware is sold. As Santa Claus said in the M&Ms commercial: "They do exist!"