# Unsigned narrow character type number representation

Tags: c++, memory

`N3797::3.9.1/1  [basic.fundamental]` says

> For *unsigned* narrow character types, all possible bit patterns of the
>   value representation represent numbers.

That's a bit unclear for me. We have the following ranges for narrow character types:

```
unsigned char := 0 -- 255
signed char : = -128 -- 127
```

For both `unsgined char` and `signed char` objects we have `one-to-one` mapping from the set of bits in these object representation to the integral value they could represent. The Standard says `N3797::3.9.1/1  [basic.fundamental]`

> These requirements do not hold for other types.

Why the requirement I cited doesn't hold say for `signed char` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signed types can use one of three representations: two's complement, one's complement, or sign-magnitude. The last two each have one bit pattern (the negation of zero) which doesn't represent a number.

Two's complement is [more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957) universal for integer types these days; but the language still allows for the others.

Comment: +1 *so* much easier to read than what I was trying (horribly) to say.

Comment: You mean the bit representing sign doesn't participate in a number representation?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: The sign bit does participate. I mean there's one bit pattern, obtained by negating zero (setting all the bits in one's complement, or setting just the sign bit in sign-magnitude) which doesn't represent a number.

Comment: Ah, two ways to represent zero... indeed, thank you.

Comment: Nicely explained, but (unfortunately) largely wrong. Yes, a signed magnitude or 1's complement representation can have a negative zero, but that's pretty much irrelevant. It would only become relevant *if* they used negative zero as a trap representation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: It's relevant in that not applying the requirements to `signed char` *allows* negative zero to be reserved as a trap value. Are you saying there's some other reason why negative zero must represent a number?

Comment: I'm saying that it's the trap representation that really matters, and negative zero is (at most) a way of producing one. It's also, however, entirely possible to create trap representations even with 2's complement where you don't have a negative zero.

Answer (score 1):

A few machines have what are called "trap representations". This means (for example) that an `int` can contain an extra bit (or more than one) to signify whether it has been initialized or not.

If you try to read an `int` with that bit saying it hasn't been initialized, it can trigger some sort of trap/exception/fault that (for example) immediately shuts down your program with some sort of error message. Any time you *write* a value to the `int`, that trap representation is cleared, so reading from it can/will work.

So basically, when your program starts, it initializes *all* your `int`s to such trap representations. If you try to read from an uninitialized variable, the hardware will catch it immediately and give you an error message.

The standard mandates that for `unsigned char`, no such trap representation is possible--all the bits of an `unsigned char` must be "visible"--they must form part of the value. That means none of them can be hidden; *no* pattern of bits you put into an `unsigned char` can form a trap representation (or anything similar). Any bits you put into `unsigned char` must simply form some value.

Any other type, however, *can* have trap representations. If, for example, you take some (more or less) arbitrarily chosen 8 bits out of some other type, and read them as an `unsigned char`, they'll always form a value you can read, write to a file, etc. If, however, you attempt to read them as *any* other type (`signed char`, `unsigned int`, etc.) it's allowable for it to form a trap representation, and attempting to do *anything* with it can give undefined behavior.