# zero assignment to signed integer in C++

Tags: integer, unsigned, zero, signed, modifier

since zero is a number that is neither positive nor negative, so what will happen if we assign a variable  of type *signed int* a value of zero in C++? Will this be a valid assignment?

In fact I have tried this assignment out and it works. But I was curious about to how it works out in first place?

Comment: The range of values for a signed integer (like e.g. `int`) is from a negative value to a positive value, and that of course includes zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to differentiate between 0 and -0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962627/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-between-0-and-0)