# Why the if statement is false as ~0 is 1 which is 1==1 should be true?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, tilde

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (~0 == 1)  
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");
}
```

why is the `if` statement false? can anyone explain?

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", ~0);` and see for yourself.

Comment: It's false because `~0` is not `1`. Did you try to read about what `~` actually does?

Comment: You mixed up the `!` and the `~` operators. Try `if (!0 == 1)  ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` Binary One's Complement Operator is unary and has the effect of 'flipping' bits.

So when you do `~0 == 1` it will check for `-1 == 1` which is false

Comment: Is the result `-1` really guaranteed?

Comment: No, it depends on what number you're taking `~` after this operator.

Comment: That's certainly true for two complements representation of negative numbers, but that's not the only alternative.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `~0` would yield `0` (or to me more precise `-0`) on a one complement machine and `-INT_MAX` on a machine with signed magnitude representation.

Comment: I was not wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table

Answer (score -2):

~0  is  equal  to  -1,  not  1.

Comment: On a two complement machine, yes. But that's not the only alternative.

Comment: @klutt: Given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c, I'm not particularly worried about that.

Comment: Yes, it's not very common with other things. But not only is your answer strictly speaking wrong when it's very easy to correct it. It also does not explain at all what the `~` actually does.