# C++ can not calculate a formula with a vector's size in it?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    if (0 < v.size() - 1) {
        printf("true");
    } else {
        printf("false");
    }
}
```

It prints true which indicates 0 < -1

Comment: While you've been already given some great answers below, I would like to point out that there would be no such question if you simply did `std::cout << v.size() - 1;`. You seem to assume that `v.size() - 1` would equal `-1`. In such cases, it's generally a good idea to back up such assumptions by simply printing the value. Or, which would be even better, learn how to effectively use a good debugger.

Comment: Unrelated, but simply solving the inequality and doing `v.size() >= 2` might me better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector::size()` returns an unsigned integer.  If it is 0 and you subtract 1, it underflows and becomes a huge value (specifically `std::numeric_limits<std::vector::size_type>::max()`).  The comparison works fine, but the subtraction produces a value you did not expect.

For more about unsigned underflow (and overflow), see: [C++ underflow and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011372/c-underflow-and-overflow)

The simplest fix for your code is probably `if (1 < v.size())`.

Answer (score 4):

`v.size()` returns a result of `size_t`, which is an **unsigned** type.  An unsigned value minus 1 is still unsigned.  And all non-zero unsigned values are greater than zero.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector<int>::size()` returns type `size_t` which is an [unsigned type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p2) whose [rank](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) is usually at least that of `int`.

When, in a math operation, you put together a signed type with a unsigned type and the unsigned type doesn't have a lower rank, the signed typed will get converted to the unsigned type (see [6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) (I'm linking to the C standard, but rules for integer arithmetic are foundational and need to be common to both languages)).

In other words, assuming that `size_t` isn't `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`
(it's usually `unsigned long` and the C standard [recommends](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p4) it shouldn't be `unsigned long long` unless necessary)

```
(size_t)0 - 1
```

gets implicitly translated to

```
(size_t)0 - (size_t)1
```

which is a positive number equal to `SIZE_MAX` (-1 cannot be represented in an unsigned type so it gets converted converted by formally ["repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type" (6.3.1.3p)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p)).

`0` is always less than `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: "an unsigned type that's at least as wide as int." Any reference to support that? (It is certainly commonly implemented that way.)

Comment: @chux AFAIK, no. But, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131833/), "The `size_t` type may be bigger than, equal to, or smaller than an `unsigned int`, and your compiler might make assumptions about it for optimization." (You know `sizeof(unsigned int) = sizeof(int)`)

Comment: @chux Thanks for the comment. I searched through the C standard and POSIX and there's no indication `size_t` couldn't _theoretically_ be `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`, either of which would change the result of that logical expression from true to false. I've edited the answer accordingly.