# How do these two conditions differ?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if you could clarify me the difference between the conditions while(k) and while(k > 0) when do they differ?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int k;
    std::cin >> k; 
    while(k) {
        std::cout << "Hello" << "\n";
        k--;
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int k;
    std::cin >> k; 
    while(k > 0) {
        std::cout << "Hello" << "\n";
        k--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting int to bool in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551888/casting-int-to-bool-in-c-c)

Comment: `while(k)` is equivalent to `while(k != 0)`.

Comment: Try searching on the internet, before asking a question.

Comment: @sweenish solved

Comment: @NitaiChandraBanik i found nothing

Comment: @Damien I know I wanted to know how do they differ

Comment: The first version doesn't take negative `k` into account. Try entering `-1` and see what happens. (Note that signed overflow is undefined in C++).

Comment: @Fabiodlt In this context, you will get the same result, if `k > 0`. Infinite recursion in the first case if `k < 0`

Comment: I mean, it does. It just matters on what you mean by "take into account."

Comment: @Fabiodlt check this link for understanding while loop: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-do-while-loops

Comment: As @Damien said, `while(k)` is equivalent to `while(k != 0)` which is different from `while(k > 0)` only if k can jump over zero and become negative - which can't happen in your example, however if you wrote a program to print k/2 lines of "Hello" and you did that with `k-=2;` instead of `k--` then there would be a difference when you entered an off number for k..

Comment: Everyone here assuming the input will always be positive.

Comment: @Fabiodlt Both versions run into [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you enter something other than a number, `abc` for example. Additionally, the first version runs into UB if you enter a negative number such as `-1`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Not sure that's really a duplicate. Closely related, for sure ... but where is the cast in this question?

Comment: @AdrianMole _"but where is the cast in this question?"_ It's done implicitely, and conditions require a `bool` value, isn't that the whole point? Also OP, confirmed, it explains their problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108612/how-do-these-two-conditions-differ?noredirect=1#comment116879720_66108612 (the auto generated duplicate comment was there before)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK - I'll concede *this time*. ;)

Comment: @Adrian Well, as always, there's nothing wrong with duplicate duplicate questions, as long quesiton and answer(s) themselves provide valuable content. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The two code snippets you present will give equivalent results ***if – and only if – the input value for `k` is not negative***.  Try it.

Specifically, for the first snippet, if a value of `-1` is input for `k`, the `--k;` line inside the `while` loop will (maybe) never reduce `k` to zero, or (maybe) just take a long time (until `k` reaches `INT_MIN` – something like `-2147483648`), depending on how the platform you are using handles [signed integer underflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011488/10871073).

The `while (k)` loop will run **until `k` is zero**.

However, in the second snippet, a negative input for `k` will mean that the loop never runs (`k` will not be greater than zero on the first test).

Comment: I mean why in the first snippet the condition  while(k) is regarded as while(k!=0)?

Comment: @Fabiodlt If you're happy that the linked duplicate answers your question, then fine. If I were to elaborate in my answer, I would simply quote that same question/answer.